# {exp:} code in CSS Not Parsing

Tags: css, expressionengine

I have an ExpressionEngine template that is some global CSS styling.  I have some dynamic {exp:} calls within the CSS.  I have a staging environment that is identical to the production environment.  However, on the staging environment, the {exp:} code doesn't parse and ends up on the client side.  This is obviously causing me problems.  Here's a snippet to show what I'm talking about:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="personal_blog" dynamic='off' disable="categories|member_data|pagination"}
    .bio_header_{personal_ee_username} {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 960px;
        height: 270px;
        background: url('{personal_header_image}') no-repeat 0 0;
    }
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I have compared everything in my ExpressionEngine files on my staging environment to the production files and I can't find anything that would be different.  Does anyone have any ideas?  This is driving me insane!

Comment: Where is this code? In an a regular EE template? In an embed? Does the Channel Entries tag parse at all, or does the whole block appear as above in the output?

Comment: It's in a regular EE template.  The type is "CSS Stylesheet".  The Channel Entries tag doesn't parse...it shows up on the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very likely experiencing this bug: http://expressionengine.com/bug_tracker/bug/18239

Are you using ExpressionEngine 2.5.3?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic parameter accepts "yes" and "no". Maybe that's the problem, you set it as "off".

Comment: True, but not the issue - that would not prevent his EE code from parsing.

Comment: That wasn't the problem.  I figured it out.  It wasn't parsing because I was calling the stylesheet wrong.  If you use the {stylesheet} tag it won't parse EE tags.  If you use the {path=''} to call the stylesheet, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have member_data disabled in your exp: tag so if that is related to the custom member fields they won't resolve.